# Java: Comparable vs Comparator - Memory & Performance

Tags: java, performance, collections, comparator, comparable

During one of my interview, I was asked

> What is the performance difference between Comparable and
>   Comparator?

I replied that I don't know. The interviewer said,

> If Comparable is implemented by a class ***Employee***, when 5000
>   Employee objects are created and added in an ArrayList, there will be
>   5000 objects with ***compareTo*** methods in heap memory. So unless
>   absolutely necessary, don't use Comparable. With Comparator, the
>   above mentioned memory overhead is eliminated.

Was he correct in saying that?

Comment: That's ... wrong ... additional methods on a class don't mean that instances of that method require more memory.

Comment: I concur with Joachim.  The method is on the class, not individual objects.  It's actually preferable to use the Comparable interface and keep Comparators for objects outside of your control or if you're doing a complicated comparison that's abnormal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That answer is incorrect.

Adding implemented interfaces or methods does not influence the memory required for individual instances of a class.

First of all, conceptually it doesn't make sense.

Implemented interfaces and methods are per-class information. Two instances of the same class will always implement exactly the same interfaces and have the exact same methods. As such, it makes no sense for the JVM to store that information per-object.

Second, you can easily verify that with sample code like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass> {

  private final long l;

  MyClass(long l) {this.l = l;}

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyClass o) {
    return 0;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = 0;
    try {
      var list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
      while (true) {
        list.add(new MyClass(l++));
      }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
      System.out.println("Created " + l + " objects before things went south ...");
    }
  }
}
```

Running this with `-Xmx32m` using Java 11 will create about 200000 objects on each run for me (with slight variations, probably due to GC details).

Removing the `Comparable` interface and/or the `compareTo` method does not significantly change that value.

You can try adding additional fields or removing `l`, which *will* change the number.

Comment: There is another point of view. Let’s assume, just for a moment, there was a special JVM requiring per-method memory in each instance. Then, `java.lang.Object` does already define 11 methods. Any real-life `Employee` class modeling some business logic surely adds another dozen or two. And the interviewer really wasted time discussing a single `compareTo` method…